# how to create a highlighting effect just like when you inspect an element with google chrome developer?

Tags: javascript

You know when you inspect an element with google chrome's developer console, there will be a color transparent mask over the element, of the same height and width of the element.

I want to build a chrome extension which can highlight all elements on a webpage of a specific class id or type on a keypress event. It would be even better if I can add text on that highlight.

Any idea how to add that highlight with JavaScript?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I tried to append an empty div as child to the element with specific class id / type, changed the background of the empty div, but the div was invisible...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a blue background maybe? If you want it when you put your mouse on the text you can use css.

1. First you have to create a class for the div: `<div class="class1">Some text</div>`
2. Then go to css and put the following: `.class1:onhover{ background-color: blue;}`

Is that what you wanted maybe?

**Edit 1**

If you want onclick just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("*").css("background-color: blue;")
        })
```